# Integrating Gumroad API into Github Pages

Tags: api, e-commerce, github-pages

So [Gumroad](http://gumroad.com) has a really cool [API](https://gumroad.com/api/authentication) and Github has some cool [Pages](http://pages.github.com/) functionality. Has anyone tried to integrate Gumroad's API with Github Pages as a store front to sell software?

Would it be worth attempting? From my quick reading on the Github Pages it looks like the page source is published in your repo. So maybe it wouldn't work too well if you had your Gumroad API key tied into it?

Just a thought that hit me while working on something today and wanted to see if anyone has successfully accomplished this with Gumroad + Github.

Comment: Hi, Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: Never did. Kinda shelved my idea on this and haven't gotten back to it.

Answer (score 2):

It would be completely reasonable to combine Gumroad and Github Pages to create a website where you can sell software.

The easiest way, however, would probably be to just add in the embed code for your products into the Github Pages website, which would work perfectly. I'm not sure if you can use Node.js in Github Pages, but if possible, you can use the higher level API's as well.

P.S. You should try to create this. I'm planning to do something similar with artwork!